# How come is this command returning "GET A LIFE!"?

Tags: unix, command, dc

I was going through a list of [Funny UNIX Commands](http://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/~ronke/FUN/unix.html) when I stumbled with this one:

```
$ echo '[q]sa[ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx]sb3135071790101768542287578439snlbxq'|dc
GET A LIFE!
```

I had never read about the [`dc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_%28computer_program%29) command, so I went through the Wiki page and managed to learn to do little things like:

```
$ echo "4 5 + p" | dc
9
$ echo "2 10 ^ p" | dc
1024
```

However, the command `[q]sa[ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx]sb3135071790101768542287578439snlbxq` sounds like too much to me. Is there any way to have it interpreted in an understandable way (and get my life back)?

Comment: Here is an "explanation" : http://www.unix.com/302938893-post4.html?s=619b3e24262a8331453fa3a31044efa6

Comment: @fredtantini oh, this seems to be the obfuscate text generator, good catch! Feel free to add some parts of that post as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> … the command
>   `[q]sa[ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx]sb3135071790101768542287578439snlbxq`
>   sounds like too much to me. Is there any way to have it interpreted in
>   an understandable way …

Relevant parts of [`man dc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dc):

> Entering a number pushes it on the stack.
>
> **[***characters***]**
>
> Makes a string containing *characters* (contained between balanced **[** and **]** characters), and pushes it on the stack.
>
> **s***r*
>
> Pop the value off the top of the stack and store it into register *r*.
>
> **l***r*
>
> Copy the value in register *r* and push it onto the stack.
>
> **x**
>
> Pops a value off the stack and executes it as a macro.
>
> **=***r*
>
> Pops two values off the stack and compares them assuming they are numbers, executing the contents of register *r* as a macro if the two numbers popped are equal.
>
> **/**
>
> Pops two values, divides the second one popped from the first one popped, and pushes the result.
>
> **%**
>
> Pops two values, computes the remainder of the division that the **/** command would do, and pushes that.
>
> **P**
>
> Pops off the value on top of the stack. If it it a string, it is simply printed without a trailing newline. Otherwise it is a number, and the integer
>   portion of its absolute value is printed out as a "base (UCHAR_MAX+1)" byte stream.
>
> **q**
>
> exits from a macro and also from the macro which invoked it. If called from the top level, or from a macro which was called directly from the top level, the
>   **q** command will cause *dc* to exit.

So,

- `[q]sa` stores the string `q` into register `a`.
- `[ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx]sb` stores the string `ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx` into register `b`.
- `3135071790101768542287578439sn` stores the number `3135071790101768542287578439` into `n`.
- `lbx` executes the string `ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx` from register `b`.
- `ln0=a` executes, if `n` equals zero, the string `q` from register `a`, i. e. exits from the macro.
- `ln256%P` prints out the byte `n` mod 256, at first 71, which is ASCII `G`.
- `ln256/sn` divides `n` by 256, thereby cutting off the last byte.
- `lbx` recurringly executes the string `ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx` from register `b`. The recurring executions yield the ASCII bytes `E` `T`  `A`  `L` `I` `F` `E` `!` `\n` successively.

---

In [UNIX fun stuff - echo and dc - obfuscate/garble a string sort of](http://www.unix.com/302938893-post4.html) you can find the script to obfuscate strings like this, together with an explanation on how to use it:

> If you save the following script in a file named obfuscate :
>
> ```
> #!/bin/ksh
> # NAME:       obfuscate -- obfuscate text read from one or more files into a
> #              string that can be decrypted by the dc utility
> #
> # SYNOPSIS:   obfuscate file...
> #
> # OPERANDS:   file    The name of a text file containing text to be
> #         obfuscated or "-" to obfuscate text read from
> #         standard input.
> #
> # APPLICATION USAGE:
> # To decrypt the obfuscated string produced by obfuscate, use:
> #     obfuscate file | read string    # Get obfuscated text
> #     Note: Do not use "read -r string" in the above command!
> #     printf '%s\n' "$string"     # Show obfuscated text
> #     echo "$string" | dc     # Decrypt obfuscated text
> #
> # Although dc can produce artibrary length output, feeding the objuscated
> # string back into dc for decryption may be limited by {LINE_MAX} and/or
> # {ARG_MAX} restrictions.
>
> # Initialize a to ASCII character set (skipping NUL)...
> a='\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\10\11\12\13\14\15\16\17\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33'
> a="$a"'\34\35\36\37 !"#$%&'"'"'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@'
> a="$a"'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\377'
>
> awk -v A="$a" '
> function cline(inline,        i) {
>   printf("256*%d+\n", index(A, "\n"))
>   for(i = length(inline); i; i--) {
>       printf("256*%d+\n", index(A, substr(inline, i, 1)))
>   }
> }
> BEGIN {   print 0
> }
> { line[NR] = $0
> }
> END { for(i = NR; i; i--)
>       cline(line[i])
>   printf("[[q]sa[ln0=aln256%%Pln256/snlbx]sb]Pn[snlbxq\n]Pq\n")
> }' "$@" | tee .dc_input | dc
> ```
>
> make it executable with:
>
> ```
> chmod +x obfuscate
> ```
>
> and execute the command:
>
> ```
> printf "Hello World.\nAre we there yet?\nLet's go home, now!\n" | ./obfuscate - | read string
> ```
>
> then the command:
>
> ```
> echo "$string"
> ```
>
> will give you:
>
> ```
> [q]sa[ln0=aln256%Pln256/snlbx]sb26160072918627741401952510855241017735603346265259888938898171600856988789569756293233903076568696999873394858335331444040snlbxq
> ```
>
> and the command:
>
> ```
> echo "$string"|dc
> ```
>
> will give you:
>
> ```
> Hello World.
> Are we there yet?
> Let's go home, now!
> ```
>
> (...) If won't work with characters that aren't in the 7-bit ASCII
>   character set and it won't work if the text you want to obfuscate
>   contains any NUL bytes, and on many systems it won't work if line in
>   files you want to obfuscate are longer than LINE_MAX bytes and if the
>   output produced by obfuscate  produces a string longer than LINE_MAX,
>   dc  may not be able to decrypt it for you on some systems.

Comment: Nicely done!! Thanks a lot for taking the time to write the answer :)

Comment: @fedorqui: I couldn't help but do it - I've been pushed for it. ;-)

Comment: Now that it is a real answer, if you don't mind I will also incorporate some infos from the [link](http://www.unix.com/302938893-post4.html?s=619b3e24262a8331453fa3a31044efa6) fredtantini provided :)